# Facebook uid retrieve different number

Tags: javascript, facebook, userid, uid

Im trying to get the uid but is retrieving different number.

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  if (response.status === 'connected') {
    alert ("Your UID is " + response.authResponse.userID);
  }
});
```

I use Graph API tool and put  **me?fields=id** . 
The result is **10000607333xxxx** (CORRECT UID)

But when I use de js code at the bottom retrieve different uid **1493309240881506**

I try with php $facebook->getUser() and is the same different number

What i am doing wrong ?

**UPDATE**
Someone tell me that is the scopeduserid but i need the global uid because with this number i have to verify if is a FAN of my page

```
SELECT uid FROM page_fan WHERE page_id = '23223322332xxx' and uid="+user_id;
```

This fql select only gave me results with the global uid.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Documento sin título</title>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
FB.init(
{
    appId  : '52150228463xxxx',
    status : true, // check login status
    cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    xfbml  : true  // parse XFBML
});


    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  if (response.status === 'connected') {
    alert ("Your UID is " + response.authResponse.userID);
  }
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are doing nothing wrong. You are getting a app scoped user id back

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook Graph Api v2.0 me/friends returns empty, or only friends who also use my app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23417356/facebook-graph-api-v2-0-me-friends-returns-empty-or-only-friends-who-also-use-m)

Comment: I need the global uid because then i have to verify if is FAN of my page with    SELECT uid FROM page_fan WHERE page_id = aaaaaa and uid="+user_id;

Comment: The app scoped user id will work too. The user need to give you the permission `user_likes` before you can see what they liked. And I suggest using the Graph API `/me/likes/{page_id}` instead of using FQL that will be deprecated after v2.0. And with that said. If you are building a like-gating feature you can stop. Facebook will not approve your use of `user_likes` so you will not be able to do it

Comment: i will try /me/likes/page id, but my chief wants this feature. Do you know where is the official note of facebook where disapproved the like-gating?

Comment: It been brought up multiple times in https://www.facebook.com/groups/fbdevelopers/ . People have been rejected for it a lot of time and Developer Operations that do the reviews have said that it isn't allowed.

Comment: If you're using a Page Tab App, why aren't you using the `page.liked` field of the signed_request?